# HERE maps - getting road type based on gps coordinates

Tags: here-api

Is it possible to get the type of road (e.g. motorway, primary, secondary) for given coordinates, using HERE maps RESTful API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "getlinkinfo" endpoint of the routing service together with the "linkattributes=all" parameter to get the corresponding functional class value of a certain link:

http://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/getlinkinfo.xml?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&waypoint=50.05564304861044,8.38889128575724&linkattributes=all

More info about the functional class value:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "calculateroute" endpoint together with &attributes=LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FC1(*) to get the road type. It returns a json value "ROUTE_TYPES" from 1...6 and each integer depending on the "ISO_COUNTRY_CODE" represents a road type. eg. ISO_COUNTRY_CODE:DEU with ROUTE_TYPES:2 is an Autobahn (motorway).

Different road types and their iso code can be found in the below link.

https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/1/doc/attributes.html?region=SAM&release=20111&apikey= your api key

Also an example url to is below

https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?&apiKey=your_api_key&mode=car&waypoint0=50.10992,8.69030&waypoint1=50.00658,8.29096&attributes=LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FC1(*)

please remember to add your own api key.