# Nokia Here Restful API - Get type of a road

Tags: here-api

I need to know, given a point (lat + long), that kind of way is (urban, highway, ...). I also need to know if the point is a city street or not.

Here
[HERE maps - getting road type based on gps coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607100/here-maps-getting-road-type-based-on-gps-coordinates)

I found an example, but the functional class values indicate only whether it is a busy road or fast, without giving me the information I requested.
I noticed that there is the "SpeedCategory" tag in output, but I could not find anything about it on the documentation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Restful call to be invoked. I write, if that can help someone:

```
http://pde.api.here.com/1/tile.json?region=<REGION>&release=2014Q4&layer=LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FC<FC>&level=<LEVEL>&tilex=<TILE_X>&tiley=<TILE_Y>&app_id=<APP_ID>&app_code=<APP_CODE>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "calculateroute" endpoint together with &attributes=LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FC1(*) to get the road type. It returns a json value "ROUTE_TYPES" from 1...6 and each integer depending on the "ISO_COUNTRY_CODE" represents a road type. eg. ISO_COUNTRY_CODE:DEU with ROUTE_TYPES:2 is an Autobahn (motorway).

Different road types and their iso code can be found in the below link.

https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/1/doc/attributes.html?region=SAM&release=20111&apikey= your api key

Also an example url to is below

https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?&apiKey=your_api_key&mode=car&waypoint0=50.10992,8.69030&waypoint1=50.00658,8.29096&attributes=LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FC1(*)