# HERE API - how to extract all the information about road based on GPS coordinates

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I need to get as much info as possible based on GPS - road type, interaction or not, etc.
What is the right way to get it?

I've seen this question and answer 
[HERE maps - getting road type based on gps coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607100/here-maps-getting-road-type-based-on-gps-coordinates)

but the provided link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the right way to do it to use the next POST request:

https://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?app_id=APP_ID&app_code=APP_CODE&routeMatch=1&mode=car&attributes=LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FCn%28%2A%29

Example of the body:
LATITUDE,LONGITUDE
37.401996,-122.041338
37.402948,-122.045580
37.403690,-122.049024

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to migrate to the Routing API, specifically the getRoute call, https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-get-route.html#resource-get-route. In the details here you can see the attribute, linkAttributes, which lets you return the information you are looking for I believe. Let me know if not.